# Postgres-XL backwards compatible with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, postgres-xl

Is Postgres-XL fully backwards compatible with PostgreSQL? If so, what extra setup is required to take advantage of the automatic sharding?

Is Postgres-XL production-ready or will it be merged with core?

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee it *won't* be merged with core from what I've seen discussed. That doesn't mean it's not good, just that the approach taken in development is incompatible with merging back into core PostgreSQL in its current form.

Comment: I'm interested in this as well, but I could only find this: http://files.postgres-xl.org/documentation/backup-dump.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by backwards compatible.   You can not take Postgres-XL tables and use them in Postgres if that is what you are asking.    It does use the standard Postgres engine for the data nodes so you can use the standard Postgres drivers and tools with it, you just have to connect to the coordinator nodes.

While it is possible it could some day be merged in I would not count on it, and even it is that will be a REALLY long way off.